# What's the cost/overhead of thread context switch?

Tags: multithreading

What's the cost/overhead of thread context switch?
So far as I know, there are direct costs:

1. Saving and restoring the context(generally,it includes general
   purpose registers and program counter)
2. Costs of thread scheduling(deciding which thread is the next to run)

And there maybe some indirect costs, such as:
If a thread switched out was arranged to run in another CPU later, then this might re-load variables from main memory(or actually from other CPU via coherence protocol), that is a cache read miss might occur.

Is there any other indirect costs?

Comment: The range is huge, assume between 2000 and 15000 cycles.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. But what about the cost in a qualitative viewpoint?